# Error with Range

Tags: vba, ms-word

So I've created a table that the user can fill out a form. They select a button that copys the entire form onto the clipboard. However, I would like the form to disable copying if they do not fill out a section, or if they type NA. Presently, when the form does this, it only works if NA or a blank answer is left on the bottom cell. How do I edit the range to include the entire table (cells 1-15)? Below is my code. (EDIT: Revised as answered, however getting an error that the requested member doesn't exist. FormFields Start at row 2 of the table.

```
Private Sub Contactcopy_Click()
' Contact Copy Macro
'Unprotect the file
If ActiveDocument.ProtectionType <> wdNoProtection Then
ActiveDocument.Unprotect Password:=""
End If
T = 1
For X = 2 To 15
Set r = ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Rows(X).Cells(1).Range.FormFields(1)
If ((r = "NA") Or (r = "")) Then
MsgBox "BLANK QUESTION OR NA ENTERED"
T = 0
Exit For
Else
With ActiveDocument
   Set myRange = .Range(.Tables(2).Rows(2).Cells(1).Range.Start, _
                 .Tables(2).Rows(15).Cells(1).Range.End)
   myRange.Select
   Selection.Copy
End With
End If
Next X
'Reprotect the document.
If ActiveDocument.ProtectionType = wdNoProtection Then
ActiveDocument.Protect _
Type:=wdAllowOnlyFormFields, NoReset:=True, Password:=""
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use cycle to test cells condition:

```
T=1
For x = 1 To 15
  Set R = ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Rows(x).Cells(1).Range.FormFields(1)
  If ((R = "NA") Or (R = "")) Then
    MsgBox "BLANK QUESTION OR NA ENTERED"
    T=0
    Exit For
  End If
Next x
```

And if T=1, then selection can be made with this construction:

```
With ActiveDocument
       Set myRange = .Range(.Tables(2).Rows(1).Cells(1).Range.Start, _
                     .Tables(2).Rows(15).Cells(1).Range.End)
       myRange.Select
       Selection.Copy
    End With
```

Comment: This code is just sample. If you send to me your file, I try to find working solution.